# npm mqtt module just keeps running without doing anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mqtt

I´m pretty new in the whole JS and node.js and npm thing and im trying to use a mqtt broker in a project I have for a class, so I installed the mqtt module from npm and to give me an idea of how it works I ran the example in the npm page but it doesn´t seem to work, it just hangs without ever printing the "hello mqtt" it says it should? im sure im missing something but i really don´t know what.
The code is:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence')
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

the page I got it from is https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt

i also tried using my own broker but it also doesnt work.

Comment: How long have you left it? Also did you look at the logs when you connected to your own broker?

Answer (score 0):

This could be so many things, but the most likely is that you are failing to connect to the broker.

The sample code has no error handling at all so it's not going to tell you when it fails to connect. Try the following code which should tell you what's going on.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var options = {
  connectTimeout: 10000

};

var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org',options)

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log("connected");
  client.subscribe('presence')
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('error', function(err){
  console.log("error %j", err);
});

client.on('close',function(){
  console.log("client disconnected");
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

I've wound the connection timeout down to 10 seconds from the default 30 so you can see it fail quicker.

Comment: i ran the code you wrote and and the only thing that prints is "client disconnected" not even "connected" prints.

Comment: You need to edit the question to answer the questions in the comment on the question